# GCloud deployment to app engine responds with a bad request

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy an app to App Engine using a Docker container (I'm running on Mac). The project has no instance initially.

These are the versions I have:

- docker v1.6.2
- boot2docker v1.6.2
- GCloud SDK v0.9.61

My Docker container runs fine locally (with **docker run** or with **gcloud preview app run** which probably means that my Dockerfile and app.yml are fine).

When trying to deploy it to production using **gcloud preview app deploy app.yml**, the server responds with a Bad Request.

```
Updating module [default]...|Pushing image to Google Container Registry...
Updating module [default].../The push refers to a repository [gcr.io/_m_sdk/dreamyproject.default.20150521t230120] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Updating module [default]...-Pushing repository gcr.io/_m_sdk/dreamyproject.default.20150521t230120 (1 tags)
Image 5c5e3f8382f6 already pushed, skipping
[...]
Image de8576728671 already pushed, skipping
Updating module [default]...\Image 4579da2d2faf already pushed, skipping
Image ad7184108492 already pushed, skipping
[...]
Image 369d7ef21685 already pushed, skipping
Pushing
Buffering to disk: 15.65 MB.|Buffering to disk: 557.1 kB
Image successfully pushed...|Pushing: [==================================================>] 15.65 MB/15.65 MB
Pushing
Updating module [default]...-Buffering to disk: 557.1 kB
Image successfully pushed...-Pushing: [==================================================>] 121.7 MB/121.7 MB
Pushing tag for rev [6de771c3b6c4] on {https://gcr.io/v1/repositories/_m_sdk/dreamyproject.default.20150521t230120/tags/latest}
Updating module [default]...done.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [400]:
  Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400
```

Did I forget to do something in the google developer console or anything ?

**edit**: deploying to a fresh project worked. I still don't know about the bad request though.

**edit 2**: after playing around a bit, I think it could be due (the bad request) to selecting EU servers when creating the project.

**edit 3**: [Error details](https://gist.github.com/Yuyuu/dd9d69cd0fbe866fc442). The thing that seems weird is the expiration date. `DEBUG: Unexpected results: {'status': '400', 'alternate-protocol': '443:quic,p=1', 'content-length': '73', 'expires': 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT', 'server': 'Google Frontend', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'date': 'Sat, 23 May 2015 11:49:41 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/plain'}`

**edit 4**: According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/V5iiwg6nWgA), Managed VMs are not available in EU projects. This should be why.

Comment: Try running 'gcloud auth login' to see if that helps.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything. I think it might be related to EU servers. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Is this because you tested on a fresh EU project vs. a normal project?

Comment: In addition to confirming whether that's the case, I'm interested whether you can still produce the failure condition? If so, I'd really be curious to see the `gcloud --verbosity debug preview app deploy app.yaml` output, as it may contain more error info.

Comment: It worked on a fresh US project and didn't on an EU one. Not sure if that was clear. I'll edit with the verbose option asap.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm in EU and created a project today. Where do I see the project localization? How do I deploy the Node hello world from here?

Comment: You can set the localization in the advanced options when creating a project.

Comment: @Mouz you should post a self-answer to this question rather than just editing the question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/V5iiwg6nWgA/gkBTNXn1LN0J), Managed VMs are not available in EU projects yet. This should be why.

> Ryan (Cloud Platform Support) - 26/05/15
>
> [...] Managed VM's are currently only available in US projects [...]

**(update)** Now on the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments):

> While in Beta, United States only. European Union-hosted applications should not deploy apps to the flexible environment.

Comment: Can you capture info from that link in case it goes down. Moreover, why not have it here so people don't have to hop around